# I don't want to see the same value repeated in mongodb collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I don't want to see the same value repeated in mongodb collection ,if I tried to keep it same value, mongodb will not allow that collection.
for eg, i have a collection:

```
{
_id:<Id of that collection>
name:"John:"
}
```

If i tried to keep again "John" as the name in mongodb collection using **Mongoose**,then it should not allow to push the collection to mongodb .so i dont want to duplicate it. please help me guys, iam trying this for 3 days.

Comment: you can create the [unique](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-unique/) index for that particular field.

Comment: Bro can u explain in code ?? :)

Comment: There is no need of any explanation you just need to google *unique index in mongoose*, you will find lots of resources, and also in stack overflow.